# New Android Studio project, use gradle cache for all dependncies instead of downloading again

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When creating a new Android Studio project I have to immediately stop it and change the gradle to a local one:

```
distributionUrl=file\:~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.3-all/a2o9bs8pjyp10tdbmwhtqkmvn/gradle-5.3-all.zip
```

or it will download all dependencies in `build.gradle` again. I then need to stop it downloading everything that isn't in the build file as it all exists in the gradle cache.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio `3.6.3` to use the gradle cache for a new project? Every time I create a new project it downloads the same files, e.g. `manifest-merger-26.3.0`, `sdk-common-x.x.x`, `kotlin-reflect-x.x.x` etc.

They already exist in the gradle cache. The build cache in `.android/build-cache` is empty and doesn't contain a `3.6.3` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has quite a number of different caches for performance reasons. On top of that Android may had its own caches.

The cache that matters for downloading dependencies is the Gradle dependency cache. You can read more about it [in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sec:dependency_cache).

This cache lives in `<USER_HOME>/.gradle/caches/modules-2`. It will be reused across Gradle versions and will minimise the network interactions for downloading dependencies.

Comment: thanks for that. I use the gradle cache but it's the non build dependencies that can't seem to be cached such as those mentioned in the question